# DSP Filter types Issues

Tags: filtering, signal-processing, iq

If I uses Low Pass Filter instead of Band Pass Filter,Is some information will be lost?
does this do any changes on the shape of IQ?

Answer (score 1):

You would not lose any more information in a low pass filter than a band pass filter if you are using the same cutoff frequencies for the low cut.  There are many ways you can lose information and it all depends on the type of filter you use, what parameters, and what your cut off frequencies are.  All of this will ultimately have an effect on your IQ, the goal is to do so with the least amount of artifacts as possible while still achieving your intended purpose of filtering.